# GPU for image processing on Pi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero-w, picamera, gpu

I have a Pi Zero W that I'm deploying headless to a remote-off grid location with very limited bandwidth. I would like to transmit images from the camera every 5 minutes or so, but to minimize bandwidth usage, I would prefer to send image diffs. Essentially like a movie would be encoded, except I would send a keyframe every hour and a frame every 5 minutes.

I can think of various ways to do this by comparing pixels individually, but I'm wondering if there's a more power-efficient way to perform this task using the video hardware on the device? What APIs etc are available for accessing the GPU that might be useful for this kind of image processing? Note that I can write C/C++, Java, Python, or even assembly if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you reminded my big disappointment a couple of years ago on hoping to do Google TensorFlow AI using RpiZ/W. It was only after I bought RpiZ that I learned the following: (1) There is a bottleneck at the USB2.0 comm interface, (2) Rpi GPU cannot do TensorFlow, because it is not open hardware. So you might encounter other AI app difficulties because of the above two or similar reasons. (3) Moreover, RpiZ is "very" slow, comparing to Rpi4B with 4GB and USB3.0, which I would recommend to use for AI projects.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but if you're willing to do custom processing you can do that no problem with the QPU (be prepared to write weird vector assembly though).
If you go that route, I made an example project [VC4CV](https://github.com/Seneral/VC4CV), and am actively using it for [my tracking system](https://github.com/Seneral/MakersVR).

It is super fast, easily can do even quite complex processing on images faster than the hardware can deliver frames, however if you really only need a frame every 5 minutes you'd probably be better off writing it on the CPU.

As for actual video encoding hardware, I don't know about that. I do know you can plug in frames you processed with the QPU as I showed above back into the hardware encoding pipeline with MMAL, so MJPEG or H264, so you could do some funky combinatory algorithm.

Or you could simply manually take the frame from 5 minutes ago and the current one and send it into the H264 encoder, it takes two as an input and uses that to send a diff already as far as I know.
That would require you using the MMAL API in C++ and stuff, shuffling buffers to and from the camera (and keeping those you need alive), and feeding them to the hardware encoder in pairs once you're ready. I did some stuff in MMAL (refer to the projects for examples) but am not sure about the entire process of if it is even possible, it's just a well informed guess seing the camera outputs always supply two frames, the last and the current one, to feed to the encoder, so I assume you can hijack that process to do your custom stuff.